# PHP DateTime with invalid Month or Day

Tags: php

I'm using docker with an php:7.4-fpm, nginx and symfony 4.4.

While testing my API with Behat i'm confused by the handling of "new DateTime()" with invalid Dates.

Query: &startDate=1900-00-00&endDate=2100-00-31

```
new DateTime($startDate); // 1899-11-30
new DateTime($endDate); // 2099-12-31
```

Query: &startDate=1900-99-01

```
// Failed to parse time string (1900-99-01)
```

Query: &endDate=2100-99-31

```
// Failed to parse time string (2100-99-31)
```

Why is the month "00" ok, and not "99"?
Why is the startDate "1899-11-30" and not "1899-12-31"?

Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: Maybe you should start with __manual__? https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php And such behaviour is __already explained__ there.

Comment: Thanks haven't looked at dateformats only at datetime object and found noting there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the document [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

You can use month 0 or year 00. Day 0 mean the last day of previous month.
If you do this:

```
$date->setDate(0, 1, 1);
echo $date->format("Y:m:d:H:i");
```

You will get this:

```
0000:01:01:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. As stated by @u_mulder it was stated in a "note" section on dateformats. Had overlooked this.